# How to remove navigation bar from splash screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have problem that is in my code i create splash screen for a time interval. When it execute then on the top of view a navigation bar is appeared.  Now i want to hide that navigation bar. How i remove for that splash screen?

```
- (void)loadView {
// Init the view
//CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
CGRect appFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:appFrame];
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.view = view;
[view release];

splashImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LS.jpg"]];
splashImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubview:splashImageView];

viewController = [[Menu alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
viewController.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view addSubview:nc.view];

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(fadeScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];}
-(void) onTimer{
NSLog(@"LOAD");
```

}

```
- (void)fadeScreen{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // begins animation block
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];        // sets animation duration
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];        // sets delegate for this block
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(finishedFading)];   // calls the finishedFading method when the animation is done (or done fading out)    
self.view.alpha = 0.0;       // Fades the alpha channel of this view to "0.0" over the animationDuration of "0.75" seconds
[UIView commitAnimations];   // commits the animation block.  This Block is done.
```

}

```
- (void) finishedFading{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; // begins animation block
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];        // sets animation duration
self.view.alpha = 1.0;   // fades the view to 1.0 alpha over 0.75 seconds
viewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];   // commits the animation block.  This Block is done.
[splashImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the navigation bar by `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;`

**The "Default" Splash Screen:**
Using the **Default.png** image functionality of iOS is a great alternative for Splash Screens. Just add an image named *"Default.png"*('D' should be uppercase) to your project and the OS will take care of the rest.

Comment: You don't even need that view controller. See my updated answer.

Comment: You don't need any code for that. Adding the Default.png image alone is enough.

Answer (score 0):

In the splash view controller, add this to viewDidLoad.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather add the navigationcontroller's view to the window instead of the splash view controllers view. Also change the frame of the splash image to have a height of 480. You can also go for Default.png as @EmptyStack suggested

Answer (score 0):

In the Info.plist you can add the property "Status bar is initially hidden" to YES and the status bar is gone forever!